# docker-compose unsupported config for services

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

I am using below version of docker and docker-compose -

```
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

I still face issues with -

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.web: 'version'
```

below is my docker file -

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - memache:memcahced
      - solr:solr
      - dev_mysql:dev_mysql
    container_name: xyz
    hostname: XYZ
    image: XYZ/mono
    version: latest
    privileged: true
 ...
 ...
```

Need some assistance.

Comment: The above is invalid YAML. You have two keys `version` at the top level. In YAML indentation is important, and e.g. build should be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: pardon me for the format of the yaml. Its becoz I did not post it correctly on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if it's just your question, but the indentation of your compose file is off, and there are a number of typos.

Not clear what you're trying to do with that `version` property in the service definition (no such property is [documented](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/)), but if you want to specify the version of the image to be used, you do that as follows:

```
services:
  web:
    image: XYZ/mono:latest
```

Comment: cool! This solved my issue! Thanks a lot @Robby!
P.S Yes Intendation is off coz of stackoverflow paste. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

As already some people pointed out, your indentation is broken. You can verify your docker-compose YAML files with `docker-compose config`. This checks `docker-compose.yml`. If you want to check a different YAML, you can specify it with `-f`, e.g. `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml config`